# Is this a valid simulation of this minesweeper-related question?

Tags: probability, simulation

The question: [Probability of getting a $7$ in Minesweeper](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822519/probability-of-getting-a-7-in-minesweeper).

Description of what I tried to do:

- Create empty $16 \times 30$ matrix
- Pick random cells and set them to $1$ until the matrix has $99$ "mines"
- For all remaining empty cells, inscribe the sum of the surrounding fields (but in a new empty matrix in the corresponding spots)
- Count the occurrences of $7$
- Do all of this lots of times (between $10^3$ and $5\cdot10^5$)
- Take the average

Results for the $3$ highest iterations: $0.02756$, $0.02751$ and $0.02749$ 
which seems quite far away (from the result derived in the answer) for that amount of simulations. Also for some reason there are never more than 4 decimals, but lots of zeroes thereafter. Is my idea and/or execution faulty somewhere?

[Code on pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/WsLs6MgK) I am not a programmer, so please be kind $:p$

Comment: Sometimes your code can put mines on top of each other. Try running it multiple times to see how much variation you get - I think you will need many more trials for it to approach the actual probability.

Comment: @TokenToucan It does, but that should not be a problem for the randomness, right? It's always around 0.0275 instead of 0.02716. Currently running 5 million trials.

Comment: With m = 5 million iterations you may be off by about 1 digit in the 4th decimal place: p = .0275, margin of simulation error `2*sqrt(p*(1-p)/m)`.